# Can I make a bootable drive for mid 2010 MBP with a Windows computer?

Tags: macbook-pro, startup

I have a mid 2010 Macbook Pro running Yosemite that I foolishly did a reset on while it was connected to an external monitor that was designated as default in settings And connected to a USB keyboard and mouse. Now I have the white screen of death on startup.

I have tried all keyboard combos to try to boot into safe mode, single user, reset PRAM, etc and none work. Yes, I know, I mucked up.

My question is; I have a working windows based desktop and is there any way for me to create a bootable image on an external drive (either USB or an external HD) so that I can at least get into some type of diagnostic on the MBP?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Command+R when booting to access your recovery partition (if Yosemite created one during installation)? That would be your easy get-out-of-jail-free card.

Otherwise you're looking at seeking the help of some kindly Mac owner who has disc images of the original install discs (or a retail Snow Leopard disc). If you put some contact details in your profile I have a friend who may be able to point you in the right direction. Once you have a disc image you can burn a disc off with any Windows disc-authoring software supporting .ISO files, which is pretty much most of them.